Calculate the inverse of $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} A_{11} & A_{12}\\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{array} \right]$
Consider a matrix of the form
$$
A:=
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\
a_{31} & 0 & 0 & a_{34}\\
0 & a_{42} & a_{43} & 0
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A_{11} & A_{12}\\
A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{array}
\right],
$$
where the entries $a_{ij}$, with $i,j=1,\ldots,4$, are complex functions and $A_{mn}$ are $2\times 2$ matrices. Is there a simpler way to compute $A^{-1}$ in this case? I've tried writing $A$ as a block matrix, and then using some ideas from the theory Schur complements to compute $A^{-1}$. However, this approach leads to monstrous entries that make the analytic computation of $A^{-1}$ very tough. Any ideas/suggestions are welcome.

This question notes the inverse of a $2 \times 2$ block matrix
$$
S := \begin{bmatrix} A & B \ C & D \end{bmatrix}
$$
is
$$
S^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} A^{-1}+A^{-1}B(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1}&-A^{-1}B(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}\-(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1}&(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1} \end{bmatrix}
$$
provided $A$ or $D$ are invertible. I'm not sure if this is too complicated for what you'd like though.

@PrincessEev That's exactly the formula that I used. Those entries are very tough to compute even with symbolic algebra packages like Maple.

@user775349: what makes you say "Those entries are very tough to compute"? What about the flexibility in partitioning the matrix e.g. into blocks of 2 x 2 or 3 x3? Are both partitions unusable for you?
